# How to change steam library location to another hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, games, steam

I had already downloaded TF2 in windows 8.1 and its kept in another drive not on the drive containing windows. Now I have downloaded Steam on Ubuntu and I want to change its library location to other hard drive. But I can't go up in the directory because its limited to the drive on which Ubuntu is installed and this drive as only 30 GB space with 10 GB free only.

How can I change steam library location to another drive so that steam recognize it?

I hope I've explained the situation clearly.

I searched for questions but they were on how to set download location to other hard drive but in my case the game is already downloaded.

[Steam Directory Settings Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Lgw.png)

[All hard drives are mounted you can see the eject icon in screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqpuP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure your game partition mounted, if not, mount it.
2. open steam,`Settings` -> `Downloads` -> `Content Libraries`
3. click STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS，ADD LIBRARY FOLDER, then chose your TF2 folder, and click ok.

If you chose your folder correctly, you can see your game in library.In order to not set library path everytime, you can change your partition to mount on startup using `disk`.

Comment: All drives are mounted. I've uploaded screen shots. Please refer to that!

Comment: I'm using wine and running steam.exe but that is in one drive while game is downloaded in another drive and by the way it runs slow in Ubuntu using windows version of steam.

Comment: why wine? steam have linux version,  go and download linux package, install it and do as above